# Hasse Diagram and Partial Orders

Tags: combinatorics, trees, lattice-orders, mobius-function, partial-functions

Consider  a  partial  order  on  piles  of  2  black  stones  and  2  white  stones.   Say  that  one configuration  of  pile  of  stones,A,  is  smaller  than  another,B,  if  you  can  join  piles  of A together to get those of B.  The smallest configuration under this order is ◦|◦|•|• while the largest is ◦◦•• .

so i drew the hasse diagram corresponding with this problem, now i must compute the mobius function of the form $\mu(◦|◦|•|•,A)$ for this partial order for all configurations of A. How would i compute one mobius function, since im assuming theres seven to be computed. I have more to add, i just have it in a rough draft. 
[image]

Now i realized i am missing an element from my hasse diagram, and how it will effect the current structure i  have ( ◦•|◦•). 
[image]

this new image is what i came up with to include the element i was missing and now i am more stuck than i was before because i apparently repeated the same thing three times in the third row ( ◦•|•|◦)

Answer (score 1):

It seems, you are only asked to calculate the value of $\mu$ on the given pair of elements (an interval), where $A$, I guess, wants to denote the bottom element, the one-pile for $A$.

Also, I'm not 100% sure that the order to consider is not just the opposite of what you wrote.

About the correspondence your picture suggests: nobody claimed that there is such a one-to-one correspondence with the subsets of $\{1,2,3\}$. Nevertheless, it's very nice that you found it, and it is indeed *almost* full. Actually, this is an injective lattice homomorphism.
And, by the way, the $\{0\}$ at the bottom should be $\emptyset$.

Comment: yes, i relized the smallest element should be on the bottom as well i mixed up my labels. But i was hoping the diagram would help me do the mobius function